# Spring Boot Thymeleaf display not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've just created a very basic Spring app using Thymeleaf, and I have no idea why it's not working. I can't even display my `<h1>` tag.

I basically get everything displayed but what I need to be displayed via Thymeleaf. The thing is I've used it before and it worked just fine. I have no idea what's wrong here and I've literaly spent the whole day looking for the solution.

I tried to upgrade my Java JDK, doesn't work (not even sure it has anything to do with it), currently using STS 4, I also tried on Netbeans 11, same result. I've added all the Thymeleaf dependencies that exist to my `pom.xml`, and I just ran out of ideas. Even in my console log I don't get anything, no exception, no warning, just nothing.

I'm aiming to program something a bit complex, so if I can't even start with such a basic stuff, I won't go that far.

Hopefully someone will help me find the solution cause I just don't know what to do anymore.

NB: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

The dependencies in my pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My Controller :

```java
    import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


import com.semweb.bikeproject.model.Station;

@Controller
public class BikeController {

    private FusekiService fusekiService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String bike(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("top", "TOP TOP MANI");


        return "index";
    }

}
```

my index.html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>

    <h1 th:text="${top}"></h1>

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:700px;">
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="msg()">
    </form>

    <script>

        var mapProp;
        var map;
        function myMap() {
        mapProp= {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
            zoom:5,
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        }

        function msg() {
            map.setCenter({lat: -34, lng: 151});
            map.setZoom(12);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSallback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried your application! It works!
I deleted private FusekiService fusekiService;
TOP MANI appears in H1 of Index html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

```
@Controller
public class BikeController {

    private FusekiService fusekiService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView bike() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("top", "TOP TOP MANI");

        //...

        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

This works perfectly...

Comment: Tested and confirmed, than you for sharing. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the Thymeleaf dependencies separately if you are using the Spring Boot starter for it. All necessary dependencies on compatible versions are already included in the Thymeleaf starter.
I would first try removing these, because the rest of your code seems fine at first sight.

Comment: I know the Thymeleaf starter should be enough (I've used it before) but I actually added the other Thymeleaf dependencies hoping it would make a difference, but it didn't. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Where did you place the index.html file? It will only be picked up if it is placed under the src/main/resources/templates directory. You can also add some logging in the request method to make sure this is being called correctly.

Comment: it is in my template directory, which makes it more confusing to figure out why it's not working

Comment: src/main/resources/templates directory it's correct! The call it's correct! You have to call http://localhost:8080/index (default port 8080)